# Do acoustic waves in liquid crystals have transverse modes?

Tags: waves, acoustics, liquid-crystal

According to a previous question:

[Modes of propagation in media](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/264796/can-sound-travel-in-the-form-of-transverse-waves)

acoustic waves in media can be decomposed in two kinds of modes: longitudinal and transverse; solids being the only one where they are both present.

According to this answer: [acoustic waves in water](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does_sound_propagate_in_water_in_a_longitudenal_or_transverse_wave_fashion_how_can_you_prove), it's due to the fact that transversal excitations in a liquid are very rapidly damped and don't propagate in any measureable way.

But, what about liquid crystals, *do* they present transversal modes?

Answer (score 1):

The transversal modes are non-propagating. Please, take a look on this article:

https://scholar.google.com.br/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=https%3A%2F%2Fjournals.aps.org%2Frmp%2Fabstract%2F10.1103%2FRevModPhys.46.617&btnG=