# Can sound waves be modulated?

Tags: acoustics, signal-processing

Can you modulate sound waves? Like can you have a sound wave of a relatively low frequency and modulate it with a sound wave of a much higher frequency which people cannot hear and send it through the air to then be demodulated at its destination?

Comment: Does it count if you convert to an electrical signal, modulate that, and then convert to sound again? I think different answers here are making different assumptions about that, and it's not always clear which one is which.

Comment: This is how we speak! (and sing)

Answer (score 24):

> Can you modulate sound waves?

Of course. In fact, back in *my* day, if we wanted to connect to a remote computer, we had to modulate our sound waves and then send them through the telephone.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem

> can you have a sound wave of a relatively low frequency and modulate it with a sound wave of a much higher frequency...?

No. It only works the other way 'round. The "carrier" wave must have a substantially higher center frequency than any frequency component in the "signal" that you want to modulate it with.

> ... which people cannot hear?

You can modulate an ultrasonic carrier wave with a relatively low-frequency signal. I am not aware of any applications that transmit signals through *air* using a modulated ultrasonic waves, but there have been practical systems for transmitting signals through *water* since the mid 20th century.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater_acoustic_communication

Comment: In olden days, TV remote controls used ultrasound through the air.

Comment: @JohnDoty, I thought about mentioning that, but the only ultrasonic TV remote technology of which I am aware was a four-button remote (channel up, channel down, volume up, volume down) in which each button operated a spring-loaded hammer that struck one of four differently tuned metal bars. I figure, it _is_ a form of signalling, but I can't really call it "modulation."

Comment: Frequency modulation.

Comment: My parents TV had an electronic ultrasonic remote https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_control

Comment: re last paragraph: it's the low end of ultrasonic, but a proof of concept using computer speakers/microphones to transmit data was published a while ago (though that used BFSK which is arguably the simplest kind of modulation) https://www.jocm.us/uploadfile/2013/1125/20131125103803901.pdf

Comment: @SolomonSlow AFAIR we had an ultrasound remote for a TV in the 1970s which was electronic, not mechanical. Buttons for multiple programs, volume and more. I could faintly hear the sound as long as a button was pressed.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it only works the other way 'round"? In terms of the mathematics of the process, it seems like exchanging the carrier and signal frequencies should have no effect, you'd get the same modulated signal either way.

Comment: @zwol, That might depend on the type of modulation. Most types of modulation used in _radio_ communication yield signals containing frequencies above _and below_ the carrier frequency. How much above and how much below depend on the bandwidth of the modulating signal. If you modulate a low-frequency carrier with high-frequency information, you're going to get "negative" frequency components in the composite signal. I'm not enough of a mathematician to know how that will impact your ability to recover the original information signal from any particular modulation method at the receiving end.

Comment: @zwol, Also, don't forget, the reason for modulating a carrier wave instead of simply transmitting the base-band signal almost always is that we want to send the signal through a channel that won't pass the base band. We want to transpose the frequency components of the signal up into the pass-band of the channel. Or, if we're transmitting the signal acoustically, maybe we want to transpose the information signal up into frequencies that people can't hear. Either way, you're not going to move the frequencies _up_ by "modulating" a low-frequency carrier with high-frequency information.

Comment: On/off is modulation with a square wave/pulse, and by that definition car parking sensors use modulated ultrasound.  The information there is just the time between transmitting a pulse and receiving the reflection

Comment: A modem does not modulate the sound wave. It generates a perfectly ordinary sound wave from the beginning, which is transmitted as-is (unless the phone operator does more things - still _electronically_, not doing anything at all with the sound waves.)

Comment: @pipe, Funny name for it though. "modem" == "MOdulator/DEModulator." Maybe they named it for what it _appears to do_ rather than for how it actually performs the trick.

Comment: @SolomonSlow No, it does modulate, just the electrical signal while OP asks for sound wave modulation.

Comment: @pipe According to [wiki modems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem) do use modulation, it's part of the name of the device.  The reason to modulate bothered me, it doesn't seem necessary ... but according to [data carrier detect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Carrier_Detect), modulation is  used to determine that an active connection is being maintained.   Once the carrier is cut the message is over and connection can end.

Comment: @StephanLuis, If you try to hook your 110 baud Teletype directly to a _voice-grade,_ analog phone line, it just isn't going to work. The phone line won't pass any frequencies below about 300Hz, and low-speed, async serial pretty much needs a channel that goes all the way down to DC. The phone line also isn't meant to pass any frequencies above 4000Hz. IDK how that affects the Teletype machine itself, but I don't think the UART on the computer end would like it. That's the problem that the first dial-up modems were invented to solve.

Comment: @StephanLuis Again: It **modulates the electrical signal**. It does _not_ modulate sound waves which is what OP asked.

Comment: @pipe can you please provide a ref for that I'd like to read more.  Right now I'm reading the wiki article on Modem and it says, 'A modem transmits data by modulating one or more carrier wave signals to encode digital information, while the receiver demodulates the signal...'  that must be sound ?  Travelling from transmitter to receiver?

Comment: @StephanLuis, Pipe is arguing that when OP said, "sound," they were only asking about acoustic energy. I.E., about waves of mechanical pressure traveling through air or other media. You and I have been using "sound" in a broader sense, including audio frequency electronic signals as "sound." An old fashioned, acoustic coupler modem actually did produce sound in the sense that Pipe is using,  but the modulation was done in the electronic domain.

Answer (score 17):

What you can do for electromagnetic waves, eg amplitude modulation, frequency modulation, etc, you can do for sound waves.  The problem with sound waves for communication is that they tend to be attenuated quite rapidly.

Here is an example of [an AM signal with 500 Hz carrier, 50 Hz modulator, raising the depth of modulation from 0 to 100%](https://www.sfu.ca/sonic-studio-webdav/handbook/Sound/Amplitude_Modulation.aiff).
The $500\,\rm Hz$ carrier was chosen so that you could hear it!

Comment: _What you can do for electromagnetic waves, eg amplitude modulation, frequency modulation, etc, you can do for sound waves_ Except polarization :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo: …except [in solids](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/264796/can-sound-travel-in-the-form-of-transverse-waves) :-)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Good point!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can, and there are even things using it (both historical and modern) for communications. However, you need a higher frequency carrier, and a lower frequency modulation (just like with EM transmissions).

The classic example of this in practice would be the acoustically coupled modems that were the norm for early long-range computer networking (and eventually evolved into the directly coupled modems that most younger generations think of when they hear the term ‘modem’). The same principle was also used by ‘modern’ fax machines, though they typically directly coupled the tone generator output to the telephone line.

In more modern usage, some IoT devices utilize acoustics to establish a Wi-Fi Direct or Bluetooth connection with a smart-phone for initial setup. Such usage typically involves a low ultrasonic frequency carrier wave modulated using some digital modulation mechanism (I believe QAM and PSK are the most common cases) to transmit a few kilobits of data (just enough for pairing) over a very short range (usually no more than 3m).

Using acoustics in this way has a number of issues though when compared to optical, electrical or RF communications. I wrote an [answer on Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56269/using-sound-waves-in-layer-1/56288#56288) a few years back about these limitations that may be of interest, but the short version is that using sound this way puts a hard limit on latency and a nontrivial limit on effective range.

Answer (score 3):

There is quite obvious example and it is called "speech".

The modulation scheme is rather complex and multiple standards are in use as of today, but the method is at least 500 million years old (including simpler schemes used by other species) and some legacy has accumulated in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make those two sound waves to perform destructive interference at the destination.(Or if I'm not understanding your questions correctly, feel free to discuss!)

Comment: Feel free to discuss where? This isn't really a discussion forum.

Comment: I mean you could take a look at the Fourier series and see how humans modulate waves and signals. I think that could help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Not only can it be done, there are commercial products using the idea**

The idea of modulating a high frequency ultrasonic sound wave with audio-frequency signals was once thought to be an interesting way to create new types of HiFi speaker. This idea failed because it turns out that ultrasonic signals have very narrow beams and this doesn't really work in domestic HiFi where the audio signal might only work if you sit in exactly the right position and don't move.

The idea [has been explored since the 1980s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_from_ultrasound) for various purposes. There are several ways to demodulate the signals including interference between multiple beams. Some non-linearities in how strong ultrasound interacts with air and surfaces can also work.

But sending audio signals to a specific place without annoying other people nearby is useful in certain contexts. And this is what the commercial applications of the technology exploit. This is what the product [Audio Spotlight](https://www.holosonics.com/) achieves.

So, high frequency sound can be modulated with audible sound frequencies (not the other way round) and there are real examples of the idea in use now.